# How to adjust the Gatsby Image placeholder background color

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm loading an image from a dynamic source and it successfully displays, but there's a flash of color that appears when the image loads before hand that's unsightly agains the white background. From reading the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image#shared-props), I saw that you could add a backgroundColor attribute to the image so I would expect that attribute to avoid that flash of unwanted color. I also noticed in my query output that there was a property of the same name: `"backgroundColor": "#5e1112",`. The backgroundColor prop I added to my GatsbyImage component seems to have no effect and I still get that pop of unpleasant color.

my query:

```
query HomePage {
  sanityHomePage {
    title
    image {
      asset {
        gatsbyImageData
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my code:

```
<GatsbyImage
  image={sanityHomePage.image.asset.gatsbyImageData}
  backgroundColor="#ffffff" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out after drilling down into the HTML of the image output and discovering an attribute named `data-placeholder-image` that had the same hex color I mentioned in my question. After reading the docs and some guesswork since Gatsby doesn't show practical examples, I found that I needed to add the placeholder option to my query like so:

```
query HomePage {
  sanityHomePage {
    title
    image {
      asset {
        gatsbyImageData(placeholder: NONE)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This successfully removed that splash of color that was there while the image loaded. It would be ideal to just add that prop to the image component itself just like you could with the backgroundColor, but adding `placeholder="none"` to the image does nothing despite it being present in the options documentation.

The other option appears to be adding it to the defaults in the `gatsby-config.js` file as Gatsby does in their [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image#customizing-the-default-options), but that would impact all images sitewide so I stuck with the query method.